# Compute the mean absolute error between two image matlab

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing

I want to Compute the mean absolute error between two image in Matlab and named it  MAE
 there is the code:

```
x=imread('duck.jpg');
imshow(x)
xmin=min(x);
xmax = max(x);
xmean=mean(x);
I = double(x) / 255;
v = var(I(:));
y = imnoise(x, 'gaussian', 0, v / 10);
y = double(y) / 255;
imshow(y)
```

Answer (score 4):

There's no need to evaluate the `min()`, `max()`, `mean()` for the first image in order to evaluate the MAE.
Since the MAE is the sum of the (L1-norm) differences between corresponding pixels in your two images `x` and `y` (divided by the number of pixels), you can simply evaluate it as:

```
MAE=sum(abs(x(:)-y(:)))/numel(x);
```

where `numel()` is a function that returns the number of elements in its argument. In your case since `x` and `y` have the same number of elements you can either put `numel(x)` or `numel(y)`.

Comment: No built in function for something as simple as this?

You could improve your answer with:
~~~
function y = mae(x1, x2)                                                   
  y = sum(abs(x1(:)-x2(:)))/numel(x1);                                     
end
~~~